# Is there any way for set Editable J2ME lwuit combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, java-me, lwuit

Is there any way for set Editable? I need to set editable for combo box in my    program. looking immediate answer...

```
public class customer_addcustomer extends Form implements ActionListener{
MIDlet midlet;

private final ComboBox c1;

public customer_addcustomer(final MIDlet midlet) {

super(".");
this.midlet=midlet;


     c1=new ComboBox();//I need to set editable for combo box

    Container cc=new Container(new FlowLayout(CENTER));

   cc.addComponent(c1);
    this.addComponent(cc);

     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codename One has an `AutoCompleteTextField` which is effectively just that.